# Error al tratar de mostrar la ruta y la imagen en java netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

estoy aprendiendo java e hice un jFrame para mostrar una imagen pero me da error con el método `getToolKit()` aquí esta el código:

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        File archivo;
        JFileChooser abrirArchivo = new JFileChooser();
        abrirArchivo.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivo de imagen","jpg","jpge","png"));
        int respuesta=abrirArchivo.showOpenDialog(this);
        
        if(respuesta== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            archivo=abrirArchivo.getSelectedFile();
            txtRuta.setText(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
            Image foto = getToolKiT().getImage(txtRuta.getText());
            foto = foto.getScaledInstance(200, 200, 1);
            lbImagen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(foto));      
            
    }
```

el error es:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: ventana.Principal.getToolKiT.getImage

Answer (score 1):

Es un bug de Netbeans al parecer.

Prueba con:

1. Abrir las propiedades del proyecto.
2. Selecciona Build-Compiling, desmarca la opción "Compile on save"
3. corre de nuevo la aplicación

Esto garantizaría que todo el código se recompila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiendo [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114025/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-sym-type)

Comment: Hola, no me funciono amigo. me apareció esto: `cannot find symbol
            Image foto = getToolKiT().getImage(txtRuta.getText());
  symbol:   method getToolKiT()
  location: class Principal `

Comment: @DimitriDrivakis ese ya es otro problema :) no has importado el paquete que necesitas para usar `getToolKit`, así que ese símbolo no es reconocidopor el compilador. Posiblemente necesites importarlo con `import java.awt.Toolkit;`
 y usar `Toolkit.getToolkit()`. Lo bueno es que ya está intentando compilar :D

Comment: me funciono usando `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` gracias por la ayuda. Escribí Toolkit y comence a ver las opciones que arrojaba. :D

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que no había importado la librería y además no sabia correctamente el funcionamiento de toolkit

```
if(respuesta== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        archivo=abrirArchivo.getSelectedFile();
        txtRuta.setText(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        Image foto = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(txtRuta.getText());
        foto = foto.getScaledInstance(200, 200, 1);
        lbImagen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(foto));
```

Comment: Este era _el problema después del problema_, diría Arjona xD